# wp_insert_post iframe missing

Tags: content, videos, oembed, iframe

In my install, I use one custom page. Here I put one text field and the fck editor. This is for the title and the content. I need to insert this into a page.

I use the following code

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $_POST['title'],
    'post_content'  => $_POST['content'],
    'post_type'       => 'page',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'menu_order'    => 10,
);

// Insert the post into the database
$post_ID = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

In the content field, I insert the content with some `iframe` videos. The page inserted successfully, but the iframe tags are not updated. They are deleted while update or insert the content.

Comment: Please care about your English and the format of your questions (and its code). Also: Take a look at [tag:oembed] and how to insert 3rd party provider videos properly in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

```
remove_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
remove_filter('content_filtered_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
 
$id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
 
add_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
add_filter('content_filtered_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Removes all KSES input form content filters.
kses_remove_filters();
 
$id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
 
// Adds all KSES input form content filters.
kses_init_filters();
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?